# How do I call methods within a constructor?

Tags: java, class, methods, constructor

Below is part of my code for class Range, and a constructor in a separate class called Tree. In this constructor, I am trying to instantiate the objects in class range over to my tree class. When I try to compile my constructor in the tree class, it says the methods I am trying to call cannot be referenced from a static context. Am I going about this the right way? I'm pretty sure this is quite an easy fix but I can't figure it out. Thanks

```
public class Range{
    int low, high;

    public Range(int plow, int phigh){
        low = plow;
        high = phigh;
    }

    public int getLow(){
        return low;
    }

    public int getHigh(){
        return high;
    }
```

---

```
public class Tree {
String name;

    public  Tree(String pname, int plow, int phigh) {
        name = pname;
        Range.getHigh() = phigh; <---where error message is
        Range.getLow() = plow;
    }
}
```

Comment: What language are you aiming to use?

Comment: You would use setters in that case, not getters. Or, better, the constructor which you already have.

Comment: use setter to set Low() and High(), call it in constructor

Comment: Sorry this is java forgot to say that, and thank you very much everybody for all the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two problems: first, `getLow()` and `getHigh()` are *instance* methods, not class methods. However, you call them by `Range.getLow()` and `Range.getHigh()`, meaning that you call them on the class `Range`. This is not allowed. First you have to create an instance of the class:

```
ran = new Range(...)
```

and then you call the methods on this instance:

```
ran.getHigh();
ran.getLow();
```

The other problem with your code is that you are trying to assing values to method calls:

```
Range.getHigh() = phigh;
```

This is not possible in Java. Java methods return values and you cannot assign to a value. That is, the method `getHigh()` and `getLow()` are meant to *read* the high and low value of a range, not *set* them. Setting these values is, in the case of the class `Range`, only possible by calling the constructor.

What you probably wanted to do, is add a member variable of type `Range` to the `Tree` class, and then set that variable in the constructor:

```
ran = new Range(plow, phigh);
```

Comment: Very good answer and also focusses on what he was trying to do in the first place instead of making everything static. +1

Comment: so I would call the Range class by ran = new Range(...) what would go in the parenthesis? =s and this would be called outside of all the methods correct?

Comment: Inside the parantheses you write the arguments for the constructor. In this case, there are two arguments, so you call it like in the last line of the answer. You have to declare the instance variable `ran` "outside of all the methods" (`Range ran;`); the `Range` constructor you have to call from withing the constructor however, because outside of the constructor you don't have access to `plow` and `phigh`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an Object of Range before you can call its methods

```
public  Tree(String pname, int plow, int phigh){
        name = pname;
        Range ran = new Range(phigh, plow);

    }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: Nor does it even compile.

Comment: Edit is no improvement. The local variable `ran` is lost when the constructor exits.

Answer (score 0):

use setter to set variable

```
public class Range{
static int low, high;

public Range(int plow, int phigh){
    low = plow;
    high = phigh;
}

public static int getLow(){
    return low;
}

public static int getHigh(){
    return high;
}

public static void setLow(int low) {
    Range.low = low;
}

public static void setHigh(int high) {
    Range.high = high;
}
```

and then call static methods to set values or get

```
public class Tree{
String name;

public  Tree(String pname, int plow, int phigh){
    name = pname;
    Range.setHigh(phigh); //---where error message is
    Range.setLow(plow);
}
```

}

Comment: Why would the members of `Range` be static?

Comment: just to set the values without initiating...if it be a non-static methods..then we have to createthe Range's object ...and do the same

Comment: So what's your real answer?

Comment: You prefer static variables why? That was my original question. It means all Ranges and Trees have the same values. Coding convenience isn't a sufficient answer. It's not a random choice 'either way man' at all.